# VCL style affects non-VCL window

Tags: c++builder, vcl, vcl-styles, c++builder-10.1-berlin

I have a problem with VCL styles in Embarcadero C++ Berlin 10.1.
I have an application written in BCB C++ and it calls pspiHost.dll (written in VS 2017), that executes Photoshop 8bf plugin filters (https://github.com/spetric/Photoshop-Plugin-Host).

Everything worked OK until I changed the project application appearance to some VCL Style. When a plugin is called from a styled application, its window is also styled!? Also, the plugin window is constantly repainted and any action in the window (like panning image) is slowed down.

I have also noticed this strange behavior on one scanner preview dialog which was also styled and it was definitely not a VCL application.

How can I disable VCL styling for non-VCL windows called from DLL?

Here is an example with Charcoal Dark Slate style:

[image: upside_down]

Please disregard image orientation (before correction for TBitmap style containers).

Here is an example of the same application without styling (windows default):

[image: corrected scanlines]

The styled plugin is completely useless (slow when zooming, panning, or any image change). The last example is with image orientation correction, but it's not relevant for this problem (just for info).

Here is a simple application. A form that has TImage, one TPanel and two speedbuttons on panel ("Load image" and "Execute plugin").

Here is an OnClick event for "Load image" button:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TfrmSimple::SpeedButton1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
// load BMP in Image1
Image1->Picture->LoadFromFile("974-1.bmp");
// set our bitmap to pspiHost - we know that it's 24 bit bgr, no alpha, so we know the TImgType
int w, h;
srcImage = Image1->Picture->Bitmap;
TImgType type = PSPI_IMG_TYPE_BGR;
w = srcImage->Width;
h = srcImage->Height;
// let's say we don't know if TBitmap has contiguous buffer, so we'll add scanlines one by one
pspiStartImageSL(type, w, h);
for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
    pspiAddImageSL(srcImage->ScanLine[i]);
pspiFinishImageSL(); // done
}
```

In this example, scanlines are "send" to pspiHost.dll one by one, so there are three API calls.

Here is OnClick event for "Execute plugin" button:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TfrmSimple::SpeedButton2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
// let's deal with filter
if (srcImage->Width < 2 || srcImage->Height < 2)
   return;
// some 8bf filter for testing
String filter = "curves3 (32 bits).8bf";
// load filter
if (pspiPlugInLoad(filter.c_str()) == 0)
   {
   void *FP = DisableTaskWindows((HWND)(this->Handle));  // so that plugin window stays on top like modal (required for some filters)
   int rc;
   // execute filter
   try {
       rc = pspiPlugInExecute((HWND)(this->Handle));
   } catch (...) {
       rc = -1;
   }
   EnableTaskWindows(FP);   // back to normal
   Image1->Refresh();
   if (rc != 0)
      {
      // error executing
      }
   }
else
   {
   // error loading -> plugin not loaded
   }
}
```

There are two API calls, load filter and execute filter. That's all.
The architecture is quite simple: Application -> pspiHost.dll -> 8bf filter (which is again DLL). Application appearance affects the plugin window. The question is how to disable such behavior?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating how to create a non-VCL window that is being styled.

Comment: I can create simple BCB project that calls 8bf filter, but I don't have a source code of 8bf filters. They're usually written in MSVC. BCB project calls pspiHost.dll, which deals with 8bf filters. If BCB project (together with lib, dll and one 8bf) is enough I can zip it and put on my site.

Comment: I dive a bit into VCL styling documentation and adding    `TStyleManager::SystemHooks = TStyleManager::SystemHooks >>  TStyleManager::shDialogs;` before DLL entry call and adding  `TStyleManager::SystemHooks = TStyleManager::SystemHooks <<  TStyleManager::shDialogs;` resolves the problem...for now. I hope that this is a right way.